# Incompatible template instances

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have two interfaces:

```
class IElement
{
    public:
    virtual ~IElement() {}
};
class IContainer
{
    public:
    virtual ~IContainer() {}
    virtual const std::vector<IElement *> &elements() const = 0;
};
```

The member `elements` of `IContainer` is supposed to return a vector of pointers to `IElement`.

Then I have two concrete implementations:

```
class CConcreteElement: public IElement
{
    public:
    virtual ~CConcreteElement() {}
    void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
};
class CConcreteContainer: public IContainer
{
    private:
    std::vector<CConcreteElement *> m_vecElements;

    public:
    virtual ~CConcreteContainer() {}
    virtual const std::vector<IElement *> &elements() const override
        { return m_vecElements; }  // PROBLEM HERE
    void doSomething()
    {
        for (CConcreteElement *pE : m_vecElements)
        {
            pE->doSomething();
        }
    }
};
```

The above does not compile, because `m_vecElements` has the type `const std::vector<CConcreteElement *>` while the return value is supposed to have the type `const std::vector<IElement *>`. Apparently, C++ does not realize the types `IElement` and `CConcreteElement` are related when they appear as a template argument.

I also tried:

```
return static_cast<const std::vector<IElement *>>(m_vecElements);
```

But this doesn't compile either. Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Comment: That reinterpret cast will certainly not work. You need to make a new vector of the appropriate type in your function and return that. The compiler *does* recognize the relationship between `IElement` and `CConcreteElement`, but there is no relationship between `std::vector<IElement*>` and `std::vector<CConcreteElement*>` to recognize. Is there a particular reason you return a `const` value?

Comment: Yes, the `elements` method is supposed to give `const` access to the elements. Not a copy.

Comment: You are returning a value, so the result gets copied anyway. And your vector contains non-`const` pointers, so it doesn't protect against modifying the pointed elements. `const` doesn't offer any protection here but may disable move semantics for your vector and perhaps other optimizations.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the reference. I updated the question.

Comment: It's true that the inner `IElements` are non-const, but that's a minor problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform this cast because `std::vector` is **invariant** on its element type which means that there's no relation (in the inheritance sense) between different vectors even if their elements are related. For more information about type variance please see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

The short answer is that you cannot do this exact thing with `std::vector` but you can do this by providing an **element getter** instead of **all elements getter**:

```
class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual ~IContainer() {}
    virtual const IElement *element(size_t index) const = 0;
};

class CConcreteContainer: public IContainer
{
private:
    std::vector<CConcreteElement *> m_vecElements;

public:
    virtual ~CConcreteContainer() {}
    virtual const CConcreteElement *element(size_t index) const override
    {
        return m_vecElements[index];
    }
};
```

Note that return type of the overriding method is **different** from the base method. This is possible because C++ supports covariant return types.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. It's kind of a workaround. If I need more of the things provided by std:vector, I'll have to write lots of those accessors...

Comment: What do you think of `return *(const std::vector<IElement *> *)&m_vecElements;`? Since pointers are always the same size, couldn't this work?

Comment: @digorydoo, this **might** work but strictly speaking it's undefined behavior because you are casting between unrelated types.